# How should I store login details for a API in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, authentication, passwords

I am using the Active Shipping Gem/API which you need to have login and password to connect to various postal services e.g. FedEx or Canada Post.  Currently I have hard coded both for each service into a separate method in the controller.  I would welcome suggestions of how to do this more securely.  Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this within a separate file for all your passwords, and then not check that file into any public repos.  To do that you need to modify your `application.rb` to look for the file with all your passwords:

**config/application.rb**

```
...
# Moving ENV variables into one place (config/application.yml)
config = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../application.yml', __FILE__)))
config.merge! config.fetch(Rails.env, {})
config.each do |key, value|
  ENV[key] = value unless value.kind_of? Hash
end
...
module Myapp
  class Application < Rails::Application
  ...
```

**config/application.yml** (example values)

```
## Rails
SECRET_TOKEN: 'asdfasfce336863e6asdfasdfasdf917ba42e6580fbbd42c01f19364a8f463ed377e46851360e3f282b0cdaf7b6332ed9e292c5e98e01acsasdf'

## Amazon
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'ascdaewecaewewf'
AWS_SECRET_KEY: 'asdfasdcae/asdfac'
AWS_REDIRECT_URL: 'aws/success'

## Environment-specific
development:
  MAILER_HOST: "localhost:3000"
  REDISTOGO_URL: 'redis://@localhost:6379'
  S3_BUCKET_NAME: "myapp-staging"

test:
  MAILER_HOST: "test.local"
  REDISTOGO_URL: 'redis://@localhost:6379'
  S3_BUCKET_NAME: "myapp-staging"

production:
  MAILER_HOST: "myapp.com"
  S3_BUCKET_NAME: "myapp"
  S3_BUCKET_ADDRESS: "https://myapp.s3.amazonaws.com/"
```

Then you can access this information throughout your app via environment variables:

```
ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
```

Wherever you would normally put the password.

This makes it easy to change anything all in one place, and it makes it easier to manage which developers get to see sensitive information.

**EDIT**

There is also a nice Railscast on it if you have a subscription: http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-revised